# Is Alamofire unable to handle UDP requests? NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=47

Tags: ios, swift, udp, alamofire

The following Swift code always returns: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=47 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Address family not supported by protocol family" UserInfo=0x7fd460f5ec40 {_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=47, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}

```
    let mSearchData = "M-SEARCH * HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: 239.255.255.250:1900\r\nMAN: \"ssdp:discover\"\r\nST: ssdp:all\r\n\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://239.255.255.250:1900")!
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = mSearchData
    Alamofire.request(mutableURLRequest)
        .response { (request, response, data, error) in
            println(error!)
    }
```

As I understand the error, it indicates that the IP address is not in the normal TCP range, but in the UDP range. I was unable to find any way to tell Alamofire or configure my iOS app to allow the request/response to be handled as a multicast.

I was hoping to avoid having to interface to GCDAsyncUdpSocket, as I am already using Alamofire in a 100% swift implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As Alamofire is built on NSURLSession, it cannot handle UDP requests without a custom NSURLProtocol implementation and overriding of the built-in manager.

You can follow [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial for NSURLProtocol](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76735/using-nsurlprotocol-swift), and then insert you NSURLProtocol into a custom NSURLSessionConfiguration's protocol classes to handle UDP, or any custom protocol.

It may very well end up being more straightforward to implement this with GCDAsyncSocket.